# access to create array in laravel Mutator

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, accessor, mutators

I want to create a new user by calling create method like this:

```php
User::create([
      'phone_number'  => '09121231212',
      'country_code'  => 'ir',
]);
```

I want to change the phone number format to international phone number format by `Propaganistas\LaravelPhone` package in phone number mutator like this:

```php
    public function phoneNumber(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => (new PhoneNumber($value, $this->country_code))->formatNational(),
            set: fn ($value) => (new PhoneNumber($value, $this->country_code))->formatE164(),
        );
    }
```

the problem is that in the phone_number mutator(set) I don't have access to the country_code that is defined in create array so I can not change the phone_number format before inserting it into the database.

also, I don't want to merge country_code to request and get it in the mutator. is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

As per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#building-value-objects-from-multiple-attributes), you can access other attributes in the getter by adding a second parameter to the closure:

```
public function phoneNumber(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value, $attributes) => (new PhoneNumber($value, $attributes['country_code']))->formatNational(),
    );
}
```

It appears you'll only able to access other attributes from the models in a custom cast:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

class PhoneNumberCast implements CastsAttributes
{
    public function get($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return (new PhoneNumber($value, $attributes['country_code']))
            ->formatNational();
    }

    public function set($model, $key, $value, $attributes)
    {
        return (new PhoneNumber($value, $attributes['country_code']))
            ->formatE164();
    }
}
```

Comment: the `attributes` is empty in set method

`
set: fn ($value, $attributes) => dd($attributes) && (new PhoneNumber($value, $attributes['country_code']))->formatE164(),
`

the document example is accessor

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The mutator [receives an instance of your model](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#mutating-multiple-attributes) to access the data.

Comment: I think the $attribute has bug so I opened an issue in laravel github
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/45860

Comment: I think I've misunderstood the docs. It's not a model the closure wants for `set` but the address class they return in the getter. It worked for me when I created a [custom cast](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts). I've added one to my answer above.

Comment: no your response was right and we can access other items of create array with $attribute but there is a bug in how you call create method in Laravel and I reported that here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/45860